# Display data in Toast Notification on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, toast

I am generating XML payload for my Windows Phone 8.1 app using PHP,like this:

```
<toast launch=''>
    <visual lang='en-US'>
        <binding template='ToastText02'>
            <text id='1'>".Input::get('your_msg')."</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>
</toast>
```

But my message is not getting displayed when toast notification pops up,notification just reads:

```
"<App name>: New notification"
```

Also,it is to be noted that I haven't used any `toastTemplate` code in my app.Any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: Is the error that the toast is not showing when the application is running or not showing at all? Further have you subscribed to the receive event and see what you get?

Comment: The toast notification behaves the same no matter if the app is closed or running. Also I have already went ahead with raw notifications and it is working fine now.

Comment: Okay, so you solved the issue? If not have you tried going into the received event and see if anything comes there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally discarded this way and went with raw toast notifications.I had to do a little more work but now it works,how I want it to work exactly.